# How to invoke the tlbexp command as post-build event to export a type library from a C# EXE from the Visual Studio 2019 IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, com, typelib

I developed a C# .EXE that defines a COM UDT (User Defined Type):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
[Guid(" ... some GUID ... ")]
public struct MyStructure
{
    ... various fields ...
}
```

I need to create a type library from this C# .EXE.
I am able to do that using the Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
> tlbexp.exe MyCSharpApp.exe
```

This command produces the `MyCSharpApp.tlb` file.

I'd like to **automate** this step using Visual Studio 2019.

So, I entered the following line in the post-build events:

```
"tlbexp.exe $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
```

[image: Post-build event settings in VS]

But, when I build the project from Visual Studio 2019, I get the following error:

```
error MSB3073: The command ""tlbexp.exe C:\Path\To\MyCSharpApp.exe"" exited with code 123.
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

How can I automate the tlbexp invocation in the post-build events?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tlbexp.exe is usually not in the path. What you can do is use this instead (without surrounding " " as you did):

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
tlbexp.exe $(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
```

This will execute the equivalent to the ["Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs)" shell command which will set all paths appropriately, and then run tlbexp:

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to surround with "..." the argument of tlbexp, in case there are spaces in the path? `tlbexp.exe "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"`

Comment: You could need " " to surround a path, but not the full command. For ex: `"blabla blabla\my.exe" args` is ok while `"blabla blabla\my.exe args"` is not